# Is there a way that I can run a mp3 file in python without opening a music app

Tags: operating-system

I am working on a poker game and would like background music to play as soon as the user runs the program. However I do not want it to open Groove music or whatever the computer uses to run files, I would like it to simply run the file by itself. Idk if this is possible? I'm using os as I can't import other things at the minute. This is the line of code I'm using:

os.system("Alexander_Brandon_-_NYC_Streets_Ambient.mp3")

Can I run it without it opening groove music?

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
os.system("nameoffile.mp3")
```